# C# TabPage inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, tabpage

I have two classes. First class has TabPage control. I want to change layout of TabPage in Child class(Class B). For example how to add simple button to tabPage control in Child class?

```
Class A
{
   TabPage a;
}
Class B : Class A
{
}
```

Comment: not specifying an accesor for your 'TabPage a' variable will make it private. This means it will not be accesible in the 'B' class.

Make the 'TabPage a;' an 'protected' and in your Class B you have access to the variable. Then you can use the 'a.Controls.Add(new Button()); to add a button to that control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the TabPage to public

```
    class A
    {
        public TabPage a;
    } 
    class B : A
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it better to declare TabPage as protected?

Comment: That will depend on your intentions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.71).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have TabPage in Class A to be public, then add the controls you want to add in your `TabPage` control collection; in this example i have added a button to the `TabPage` you can add many more controls similarly.

```
class A
{
    public TabPage a;
} 
class B : A
{
        //Create a control to add and set its properties
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        btn.Size = new Size(120, 25);
        btn.Text = "My new Button";
        //Add the control to the Tabpage.
        a.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

It really depends upon your situation, if you want to have TabPage accessible from base class too, make it public otherwise protected.

**For protected**

```
class A
{
    //Visible only to Inheriting class;
    protected TabPage a;
} 
class B : A
{
        //Create a control to add and set its properties
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        btn.Size = new Size(120, 25);
        btn.Text = "My new Button";
        //Add the control to the Tabpage.
        a.Controls.Add(btn);
        //This will be visible to everybody
        public TabPage b= a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it better to declare TabPage as protected?